# Correct command on 'gddrescue'

Tags: data-recovery, ddrescue

I'm using gnu ddrescue by Antonio. I have a broken, but not dead (checked by the photorec utility - it found and saved many files on it) a 1 terabyte usb-HDD and the goal is to create its RAW-file. After a long search on the Internet I stopped on the command `ddrescue --force --direct --retrim`, In addition, in the original recommendation was the line "-max-retries = 3", but since the console gave an error, I deleted it. For more than a week there is a process. So all long. Yes. Progress is shown in the screenshot.

[image: screen console] Am I doing everything right? Can I hope for a successful outcome at the end of this process? The output file weighs 0 bytes, although the free space on the source hard disk is reduced - why?

Comment: I think `Current status, rescued: 0 B` shows that no data has been rescued yet. This corresponds with 0 B of the output file you report. Do I read you right that this process has been running for over a week? `run time: 6m 5s` says something else. Maybe `ddrescue` hung? Is there anything in `dmesg` that seems relevant? What do you mean by "free space on the *source* hard disk is reduced"? As I see it, your source is `/dev/sda`; is it mounted and monitored, so you can tell its free space? Next: `osboxes` – is it a virtual machine? If it is then how exactly is `/dev/sda` connected to it?